# How to change the k8s internal ip addresses?

Tags: networking, centos, docker, kubernetes, calico

I provisioned a kubernetes cluster on my own couple of virtual machines via kubespray. 
The VM's network is bridged adapter and kubespray uses calico as default network-plugin.

Before sometime, I've switched to another network and as a result of the router change, the internal IP addresses have been changed.

When I run `kubectl get nodes` on the master node I get -
`Unable to connect to server : dial tcp <master previous IP>:6443: connect: network is unreachable`
In addition, the vm doesn't generate a new ip for the machine (- from the current router.).

My question is, How can I change the ip's of the nodes ?

Attached is the screenshot of my laptop that shows the k8s nodes and the column I wish to edit. 
(- The screenshot is fro when I've been connected to the network via the previous router.)

[image]

Thanks in advance for any help !

Comment: If I understood correctly, you want to change the node IP. This column display the nodes IPs, so you need to change the IP in your OS and re-join the nodes again, because Kubernetes doesn't manage this IPs. Could you confirm if I understood correctly, and if not give more details about or issue?

Comment: No. I shutdown all the servers and now I have new ip's (- even for the master itself.). And the master dosn't success even to show the nodes. As, it tell me that it tries to connect to the previous master ip.

Comment: To use a Kubernets cluster you need first of all configure your nodes with static IP, and them make the k8s installation. Do you performed this steps before install the cluster?

Comment: No. So, As I understand the only one option is to reinstall ?!

Answer (score 1):

The collumn `INTERNAL-IP` show your nodes IPs, Kubernetes doesn't manage this IP's.

Is recommended configure **static IP** for all your nodes before setup your Kubernetes cluster to avoid problems like this.

I see 2 alternatives:

1. Set static ip  displayed in `INTERNAL-IP` on your nodes, for examples:

Your `kubectl get nodes` show `node2` with ip `192.168.43.118`, so in `node2` you need to configure this ip and reboot the node. The same step for all nodes.

[How to configure static ip on Ubuntu](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-configure-static-ip-address-on-ubuntu-18-10-cosmic-cuttlefish-linux)

[How to configure static ip on CentOS](https://www.mustbegeek.com/configure-static-ip-address-in-centos/#.XnN9OchAoZ8)

2. Edit the `--node-ip` in kubelet config on the node for the new IP, see [this](https://medium.com/@kanrangsan/how-to-specify-internal-ip-for-kubernetes-worker-node-24790b2884fd) reference.

References:

[https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/kubelet/](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/)